# Cannot create MySQL Table with Spring @Entity Annotation

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a problem with creating a `TABLE` from `Client` class with `@Entity` annotation.

My `Client` class:

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Persistable<Long> {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;


private String firstName;
private String lastName;


public Client(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public Long getId() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isNew() {
    return false;
}
```

}

My `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mealsdeals
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=webServices

#just for first run - delete or comment out
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialize=true

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.schema=schema-mysql.sql
spring.datasource.data=data-mysql.sql
```

My `Main` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer{


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
}
```

The **ERROR-STACK** contains four main issues:

> ResourceNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/schema-mysql.sql] defined by 'spring.datasource.schema' does not exist
>
> Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed
>
> Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>
> Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expression

When I outcomment the lines `spring.datasource.schema=schema-mysql.sql` and `spring.datasource.data=data-mysql.sql` the application runs with no error but no data is stored into database.

Comment: Where are you storing the `schema-mysql.sql` and `data-mysql.sql` files? Can you provide the directory structure of these files?

Comment: i dont have those files. i was under the impression that these are added by maven-dependencies. I have looked at another working project where those files aren't added manually. I just want to store my client in the database nothing more.

Comment: FYI Spring has no such `@Entity` annotation. That is a JPA annotation.

Comment: When you say `no data is stored`, what exactly do you mean? What SQL statement are you running to verify the data, in what database, and what is the output of the SQL?

Comment: @SteveOhio [Here](https://github.com/praveenprem/security-sample) sample project I created. Have a look in the `/src/main/resources/templates/` folder and `AppConfig.java` file for an example. At the end, you're going to have to create the `schema-mysql.sql` and `data-mysql.sql`.